# How to import files from a directory using webpack resolve

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to do this:

File structure

```
/app
/app/components
/app/containers
/app/reducers
/app/actions
```

I want to be able to be in any of the files within `/app` and do an import like this

```
import {ComponentA} from 'components'
```

without having to have an `index.js` in each of the folders containing something like this:

app/components/index.js

```
export * from './ComponentA'
export * from './ComponentB'
```

I was thinking the I could do this using [webpack resolve](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve), but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this the correct way.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need require.context: 
https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html

for example to require everything including subdirectories in the "tasks" folder: 
require.context("./modules/tasks/", true, /.*/);

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use a combination of [`root`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root) and [`modulesDirectories`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-modulesdirectories) parameters of the `resolve` property. With the first you have to set up root of the your new modules tree as it is shewn in the documentation's example:

```
var path = require('path');

// ...
resolve: {
  root: [
    path
  ]
}
```

And if it is required you are able to use the specific list of subfolders in the *app* folder to import from them only do as follows:

```
resolve: {
  modulesDirectories: [ 'node_modules', 'app' ]
}
```

The first argument is required to allow importing from original *node_modules* folder.

Then you be able to import as follows:

```
import ComponentA from 'components';
```

But make sure that the *components* and other sibling folders have the similar to *node_modules* structure like *node_modules/package/lib/Module* and for your case *app/components/lib/ComponentA* includeing *package.json* with `files` section in the root of *components*.